# Integrate paypal iOS SDK for restaurant app

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, sdk

Would it be acceptable to integrate the `PayPal` iOS sdk (from https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) for an iOS app that allows users to order from a restaurant. To place the order, users could pay with cash or paypal. so paypal SDK sounds ideal here. would Apple reject such app?

Assuming Apple would be ok with above thing, are there any docs or guidelines for integrating and making sure user doesn't reuse old payment?

Comment: 1.in which account money is deducted and in which it transfer?

Comment: A user using this app will pay for food ordered from restaurant using his/her paypal account or via credit card processed by paypal and the money is received by merchant (in this case restaurant owner).

Answer (score 2):

There's an iOS SDK for `PayPal`, so, based on that, it should be allowed on the app store (and it is).

Your app will not be rejected if you use `PayPal` in it, unless you're tricking users into buying something fake. Using it for a legitimate reason will be fine.

[Here is a guide to using the `PayPal` SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, its a simple fast-food ordering app for patrons in neighboring zip codes. Nothing to trick :) I couldn't find any other SDK like PayPal's mobile SDK for in-app purchase.

Comment: 1.in which account money is deducted and in which it transfer?

Comment: @PatelMaulik I'm not sure - I personally have not used the PayPal SDK in any iOS apps. You would have to look at the docs for that info